# How can I use the kd-tree file exchange and mex in matlab?

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mex, kdtree

I want to use the file exchange about kd-tree in matlab and search in mathwork site and saw the below m-files but I cant understand how can I mex files.
in comments "Kuan-Ting Yu" say: 1. use mex -setup to find your compiler. E.g. VS 2010 
2. in "kdtree_common.h", replace #include "c:/.../mex.h" with "mex.h" 
3. dir to ./src and mex all .cc file
what is his mean?
haw can I mex all .cc file?
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4586-k-d-tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mex all source files, you have to call the [mex](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) function.

To call mex for all cc-files in a directory, use

```
for file = dir('*.cc'); mex(file.name) ; end
```

Comment: thanks... how can I find my compiler using mex -setup ?

Comment: Is a compiler compatible to your matlab version installed? Then run mex -setup and it should find it automatically. If not, what compiler, which matlab version?

Comment: my matlab versian is 7.12 matlab 2011 a
and No supported SDK or compiler was found on this computer. 
For a list of supported compilers, see  
http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2011a/win64.html 
was my error